# Auto Tagging WooCommerce Products according to the Price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'auto_tag_product_by_price', 10, 1 );

function auto_tag_product_by_price( $product_id ) {
  $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
  $price = $product->get_price();

  // Define your price ranges and corresponding tag IDs here
  $price_ranges = array(
    'budget' => array( 'min' => 0, 'max' => 100, 'tag_id' => 123 ),  // Replace 123 with your tag ID
    'mid-range' => array( 'min' => 101, 'max' => 200, 'tag_id' => 456 ),  // Replace 456 with your tag ID
    'premium' => array( 'min' => 201, 'max' => 9999, 'tag_id' => 789 ),  // Replace 789 with your tag ID
  );

  $assigned_tag = null;
  foreach ( $price_ranges as $tag_name => $range ) {
    if ( $price >= $range['min'] && $price <= $range['max'] ) {
      $assigned_tag = $range['tag_id'];
      break;
    }
  }

  if ( $assigned_tag ) {
    $product->set_tag_ids( array( $assigned_tag ) );
    $product->save();
  }
}
```

I am trying to automaticlly tagging products according to their prices at that moment but couldnt manage to do it. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Firstly sorry, English is not my first language so I didnt want to keep it long with a lot of text. I am trying to create 3 tags which are named " Under X Dollars", X being 5, 10, 15 and such. So if there are 10 products priced lower then 15, they will be tagged as "Under 15 Dollars". The most reasonable action for this is, well not a action but WP Cron which will check it, say every 1 day, but because it makes it even more complicated, I tried to do it with a update product action

Comment: But I didnt add WP Cron, I am using woocommerce_update_product action at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The following simplified and revised code version, will also handle variable products (based on the variation max price), adding a product tag based on the product price by ranges:

- with a price up to $200, the product will be tagged with `789` term ID,
- with a price between $100 and $200, the product will be tagged with `456` term ID,
- with a price lower than $100, the product will be tagged with `123` term ID.

Try this replacement code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'auto_add_product_tag_based_on_price', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'auto_add_product_tag_based_on_price', 10, 2 );
function auto_add_product_tag_based_on_price( $product_id, $product ) {
    // Handle all product types price
    $price = $product->is_type('variable') ? $product->get_variation_price('max') : $product->get_price();

    if ( $price >= 200 ) {
        $term_id = 789;
    } elseif ( $price >= 100 ) {
        $term_id = 456;
    } else {
        $term_id = 123;
    }

    if ( ! has_term($term_id, 'product_tag', $product_id) ) {
        wp_set_post_terms($product_id, [$term_id], 'product_tag'); 
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.